# jquery mobile listview look and feel not working android 2.3.3?

Tags: android, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing android apps using phonegap + Jquery mobile. My apps displaying the list in listview div but look and feel of listview not working on 2.3.3 and working fine on version greater than 3.0.
following is the my index.html page. please suggest me answer.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        
        <title>ListView</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="courseList">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    Course List
                </h3>
             </div> 
            <div data-role="content">    
                <!-- <div class="example-wrapper" data-iscroll> -->
                     <ul data-role="listview" id="output" data-theme="b">
                    </ul> 
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>  
         </div>
  </body>
  <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   
    if(window.isphone) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    } else {
        onDeviceReady();
    }
    
});

// device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
     $.ajax({
        url:"http://www.cilibrary.ojaswitech.com/getLatestNews",
       // crossDomain: true,
        //type       : "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
             $.each(result, function(i, item) {
                    $('ul').append('<li><a href="">' + item + '<p></li>');
                 });
        $('#output').listview("refresh"); 
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(xhr.status);
             alert(thrownError);
        }
    })    
} 
</script>
</html>
```

following is the two images. first is left side image 2.3.3 and second is right side image 4.2.2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug which is introduced in version 1.4.1 and effects Android 2.3.x devices and IE8. The problem is in lines `3195` and `3222` of `jquerymobile.js`. There's a `default` property which happens to be a reserved keyword.

You can solve this problem either by modifying these two lines;

```
duration = $.fn.animationComplete.default; // this
duration = $.fn.animationComplete.defaultDuration; // to this
// and
$.fn.animationComplete.default = 1000; // this
$.fn.animationComplete.defaultDuration = 1000; // to this
```

or wait until version 1.4.2 is out with the fix for this bug.

[Reference](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7116)

Comment: Thanks for your answer..but there is other issue also in jquery mobile thats why i did not use jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Acctually there might be an even easier way. Try with replacing:

```
$('#output').listview("refresh");
```

with this instead:

```
$('#output').listview("create");
```

=) Good luck! 
Danny